# Как добавить в localstorage массив

Tags: angular

У меня есть класс:

```
export class Clothes{

  vendorCode = "";

  name = "";

  image?:any =  " http://localhost:44408/assets/images/" +[];

  amount = "";

  price = "";

  description:any;

  size:any;

}
```

Я получаю данные из БД, которые тоже класса clothes:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.clothesService.getClothesUrl(this.VendorCode)
      .subscribe((result)=>(this.clothes = result));
  }
```

Я хочу сделать корзину в localstorage, которая будет хранить товары:

```
  setCartJson() {
    this.ShoppingCart.price = this.clothes.price;
    this.ShoppingCart.vendorCode = this.clothes.vendorCode;
    this.ShoppingCart.size = this.clothes.size;
    this.ShoppingCart.amount = this.clothes.amount;
  }
 

ShoppingCart:Clothes;
  addCart(clothes:Clothes){
    this.setCartJson();
    var result = localStorage.getItem('Cart');
    result += JSON.stringify(this.ShoppingCart);
    // @ts-ignore
    localStorage.setItem('Cart',result)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.clothes))

  }
```

Но с реализацией  явно что-то пошло не так. Возможно, это можно реализовать иначе, но я не знаю как. Подскажите, как правильно это сделать и в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Вам нужно result перевести в объект, после чего слить его с  ShoppingCart потом обратно в строку) так, на вскидку..

Comment: `result += JSON.stringify(this.ShoppingCart)` так делать не стоит если Вы последовательно объедините две json строки вам потом никакой парсер не поможет

Comment: если в localStorage храните массив, то сначала его парсите в массив, потом добавляете элемент, и снова переводите в строку

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответы. Я решил грузить в localstorage только название товара, ибо просто вся информация не поместится в него, а дальше по названию выгружать определенные единицы товара из БД. Соответственно, вопрос отпал сам собой, ибо упростил себе задачу. Напишите кто-нибудь ваш комментарий как ответ, чтобы я отметил.